# Basic probability proof

Tags: probability, proof

I'm currently looking through the proof of this lemma and I am getting stuck at this (trivial!) stage of the proof and I was wondering if someone could help? I've written up the part of the proof that I am stuck on -

**Lemma** Let X, Y be random variables, let a be a real number and ε > 0. Then

$P(Y\leq{a})\leq P(X\leq a+\epsilon) + P(|Y-X|>\epsilon)$

**Proof**

$P(Y\leq{a})=P(Y\leq a, X\leq a +\epsilon) + P(Y\leq a, X> a +\epsilon)$

$\leq P(X\leq a +\epsilon) + P(Y-X\leq a-X, a-X< -\epsilon)$

$\leq P(X\leq a +\epsilon) + P(Y-X< -\epsilon)$

$\leq P(X\leq a +\epsilon) + P(Y-X< -\epsilon) + P(Y-X> \epsilon)$

$ = P(X\leq a+\epsilon) + P(|Y-X|>\epsilon)$

The proof seems to imply that $P(Y\leq a, X\leq a +\epsilon) \leq P(X\leq a +\epsilon)$

But I don't understand why this is true?

Comment: Hint: P(x<=a+ e) is computed over all the domain of y. Try to write both parts in terms of integral and double integrals then it might be more clearer. Sorry, I'm writing using my cell phone.

Comment: Nowhere did it say that X and Y were both continuous.

Comment: This what I assume just to help him see the relation.

Answer (score 2):

It's always a good idea to reduce such manipulations to the axioms of probability (and, if needed, simple algebra).

Begin by noting we can decompose the sample space  $\Omega$ into the union of any event and its complement:

$$\Omega = \{|X-Y| \gt \epsilon\}\ \bigcup\ \{|X-Y| \le \epsilon\}.$$

This breaks the event $Y \le a$ into two *disjoint* parts,

$$\{Y \le a\} = \left(\{Y \le a\} \cap \{|X-Y| \gt \epsilon\}\right)\ \bigcup\ \left(\{Y \le a\} \cap\{|X-Y| \le \epsilon\}\right).\tag{1}$$

Because these parts are disjoint, their probabilities will add (that's an axiom).  Let's tackle the evaluation of the probabilities separately.

#### Left hand side

Another axiomatic relationship is that the probability of a subset of an event is never greater than the probability of the event itself.  This allows us to overestimate the left hand portion of $(1)$:

$$\Pr\left(\{Y \le a\} \cap \{|X-Y| \gt \epsilon\}\right)\le \Pr(|X-Y| \gt \epsilon).\tag{2}$$

This is intuitively clear.

#### Right hand side

The right hand portion is due to the algebraic fact that inequalities add:

$$Y \le a\text{ and } |X-Y|\le \epsilon\ \text{ implies }\ X= Y + (X-Y) \le a + \epsilon.$$

(This is readily deduced from the triangle inequality.)

Therefore the right side of $(1)$ is a subset of a simpler event $X \le a+\epsilon$.  Once again this gives an inequality of probabilities

$$\Pr\left(\{Y \le a\} \cap\{|X-Y| \le \epsilon\}\right) \le \Pr\left(X \le a+\epsilon\right).\tag{3}$$

Intuitively, if $Y$ does not exceed $a$ and $X$ is within $\epsilon$ of $Y$, then $X$ cannot exceed $a+\epsilon$.

#### Solution

Taking probabilities in $(1)$  by means of the results $(2)$ and $(3)$ yields

$$\Pr(Y \le a) \le \Pr(|X-Y| \gt \epsilon) + \Pr\left(X \le a+\epsilon\right),$$

*QED*.

Putting this result in words might help the intuition:

> The chance of $Y \le a$ cannot be greater than the chance that $X \le a+\epsilon$ (if $X$ is within $\epsilon$ of $Y$) plus the chance that $X$ is more than $\epsilon$ away from $Y$.

Comment: @whiber Okay you were more thorough so you get credit for that.  When the OP concentrates on one issue it is hard to know what aspect of the proof is already clear to him and doesn't need comment. We all worked hard on P(A and B)<=P(B) because the OP gave us a hard time about it.  You came in late and cleaned up. I gave you an upvote. I don't know if the OP even cares about your answer.  But I know your feeling is that thorough answers are better for the community in general.

Comment: I got no credit and I was the first to respond to the OPs main question.

Comment: @Michael  When a post is not very readable it's unlikely to get many upvotes.  Allow me to give a little advice.  First, learn how to apply MathJax markup.  It's a useful skill and you can pick up the basics in minutes (by emulating and copying markup from other posts).  Second, make a habit of explaining which part or parts of the question you intend to address. Always include a statement summarizing your post's contribution.  Third, if there is any outstanding issue concerning what the question is asking, then try to resolve it (via comments) before posting an answer.

Comment: Does MathJax help me make my equations look better like Latex does?  I don't know anything about it. Had I done what you suggest it is not clear that i would have gotten credit anyway. Of course people can still give me credit now.  I don't think I am alone. ab90hi gave an answer without explaining that he was only answering part of the question.  I think we both may have thought we were answering the question completely because we addressed everything the OP asked.

Comment: @Michael MathJax implements a (large) subset of $\TeX$. Help is available from a button when you're typing an answer. More help is readily found by Googling.  Learn quickly by locating a post on a related subject (in another browser pane), right-clicking on a MathJax-formatted expression, selecting "Show Math As...", and choosing "Tex Commands". Copy the markup from the little window that appears and paste it into your own text, surrounded by dollar signs. Edit it from there.  Finally, see our [meta thread](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1604).

Comment: Thanks.for the suggestions.  You always try to be helpful to others.

Comment: Isn't the question asking about why $P(Y\leq a, X\leq a +\epsilon) \leq P(X\leq a +\epsilon)$ ?

Comment: @JuhoKokkala I agree and the OP has not expanded the question to address the other part that Bill Huber put in his answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That clears things up a lot, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Let the us define the following events

$A = \{X \leq a+e\}$, $B = \{X \leq a+e,Y\leq a\}$, and $C = \{X \leq a+e,Y>a\} $

Now,
\begin{equation}
A = B \bigcup C
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\implies B \subseteq A \implies P(B) \le P(A)
\end{equation}

Comment: But this is the opposite of what I need to prove right?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ appear to have switched in the last row ( $A=B\cup C$ implies  $B\subseteq A$, not $A \subseteq B$)

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I have made the edit to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

That part is easy as you suspect. Let the event A={X<=a+e) and B= {Y<=a} then you have P(A and B) <= P(A) simply because the event  {A and B} is a subset of A.

Comment: But shouldn't the fact that they are two different random variables make a difference here?

Comment: No They live on the same probability space.

Comment: If you assume that x and y are independent, then p(y<=a, x<=a+e) = p(y<=a)p(x<=a+e). Then since probability <=1, the relation holds true.

Comment: But X and Y are not assumed to be independent and it is still true.  There is no need to say P(A and B) = P(A) P(B) where A and B are as I defined in my answer.  For any two events U and V if U is a subset of V P(U)<= P(V).

Comment: This answer is suspect: why doesn't the event $|X-Y\gt \epsilon|$ ever enter into consideration?

Comment: @whuber I didn't check or claim that the result was correct,  The OP was puzzled about a simple and obvious result and that is why I ignored it.  Looks like the OP kept arguing that point until ab90hi gave his argument.

Comment: My comment above is incorrect.  There have been so many comments scattered under various answers that it gets confusing.  ab90hi got the first upvote and the OPs only comment thus far is regarding confusion about ab90hi answer.